# Sigma 10-20mm F3.5 EX DC HSM ($329) or Nikon AF-P DX NIKKOR 10-20mm f/4.5-5.6G VR Lens ($277)?

Tags: nikon, wide-angle, nikon-d7200

I have a Nikon D7200 and I am planning to buy a wide angle zoom and I have narrowed down my choices to the below two.

1. Sigma 10-20mm F3.5 EX DC HSM ($329)
2. Nikon AF-P DX NIKKOR 10-20mm f/4.5-5.6G VR Lens ($277)

Price wise both are close but Sigma is a slightly faster lens and I think it does not have image stabilization while the Nikon has VR.

Nikon also has a plastic mount vs. Sigma's metal. And also Nikon weighs 230g vs. Sigma's 560g.

Which one should I choose? (I am not a professional photographer).

Thank you.

Comment: Lenses with plastic mounts are made to break.

Comment: Rent both: pick the one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the fragility of plastic mounts and that I could rent the lenses. This is useful information for me.

Comment: Which is better for you totally depends upon what you plan to do with it. You need to tell us that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the circumstances. For example, if you are going to use the lens a lot, metal mount would be preferable. Similarly when shooting moving targets in low light (every artificially lit indoor environment is low light!) Sigma is better.

However, don't ignore the weight aspect. If you are looking to have a wide angle lens all the time with you, and don't shoot in low light (or shoot only non-moving targets in low light), and don't use the lens so much that the plastic mount would break, pick the Nikon.

I'm not familiar with the autofocus speed and accuracy of 3rd party lenses in the Nikon world, but at least in the Canon world either the speed or accuracy of 3rd party lenses is likely to be non-optimal. Official Canon lenses do not have the problems.

I assume the Sigma does not have image stabilization. It can more than make up for the difference in lens speed, but only if shooting non-moving targets.

Also, this goes without saying: ensure both lenses are compatible with your camera. (I didn't; my answer assumes you already did your research.)

Comment: Yes, I checked and both the lenses are compatible with my camera. I have decided to go with Nikon lens for now.

Comment: See this previous question on plastic vs metal https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/57062/1943